# Send data to asp.net server using volley android

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to send data to the server from my android app I searched about volley and wrote the code below but it does not work properly can you give me a hand to fix it?

I use a map for getting data then I extract the keys and put them to a string array:

```
keys=new String[data.size()];
data.keySet().toArray(keys);
```

after that i make my request like this:

```
for (int i=0;i<data.size();i++) {
    requestJsonObject.put(keys[i], data.get(keys[i])); 
}
```

Here is the complete code:

```
public  class  ApiPostData {

    private static final String TAG = "PostData";
    private String url;
    private HashMap<String,String> data=new HashMap<>();

    String[] keys;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public ApiPostData setData(HashMap<String, String> data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    public ApiPostData setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
        return this;
    }

    public void PostData(final OnSetSettingComplete onSetSettingComplete) {
        JSONObject requestJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            keys=new String[data.size()];
            data.keySet().toArray(keys);  
            for (int i=0;i < data.size(); i++) {
                requestJsonObject.put(keys[i], data.get(keys[i])); 
            }
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestJsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        int success = response.getInt("statusCode");
                        onSetSettingComplete.onResponse(success);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            });

            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(10000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            Volley.newRequestQueue(G.context).add(request);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "EpostData: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public interface OnSetSettingComplete {
        void onResponse(int success);
    }

}
```

Comment: you can use okhttp, it's usefull, simple and sweet

Comment: do you have a sample code ?

Comment: `but it dose not work properly` what doesn't work properly , what's the error?

Comment: Data can't be sent to the server there is no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suggest using okhttp

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
RequestBody body = new     FormEncodingBuilder().add("key1","value1").add("key1","value2").add("key3","valu    e3").build();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("URL HERE")
        .addHeader("Some Headers Here", "Header Values Here")
        .addHeader("Some Headers Here", "Header Values Here")
        .post(body)
        .build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: What  "addHeader" do?

Comment: you can add some headers like 'cookie' or 'cache-control' or something else to your request